# Redirect Url not working and getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to send an Ajax request to a Nodejsserver from my application, but getting this error

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am sending request using ajax call to a server (nodejs), server in turn will return url , in success function, should redirect the url sent by server.

```
//nodejs app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var link= require('./routes/link');


app.use('/quote', link);

app.use(cors());

module.exports = app;

//link.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({ redirectUrl: "https://www.google.com" });
});

module.exports=router;

//frontend
$.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/quote',
      data: {
        id: "1",
        cn: "IN",
      },
      success: function (result) {
          window.location.href = result.redirectUrl; // url got from server
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.error);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can custom cors instead of `app.use(cors());` like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

Let try it.

Comment: I have tried but this is not working, am getting `result` as `undefined` as well in success function

Comment: result undefined, I think cors okay.

Comment: result is undefined, cors is okay.

Comment: ```Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```  sorry `undefined` was console in error function

Comment: window.location.href = result.redirectUrl; here is you problem, you let do it: window.location.href = result;

Comment: the result is undefined?

Comment: I tried ```alert(result); in success function``` but getting ```no access control origin error``` and ```error console function``` displays ```undefined```

Comment: Its not passing through the success function i guess

Answer (score 0):

Order matters here just move "app.use(cors());" above "app.use('/quote',link);" like this. I doubt you need to fill out the custom fields in cors, the correct order should fix the problem.

```
  //nodejs app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var link= require('./routes/link');

app.use(cors());
app.use('/quote', link);
...
```